# Problema com formatação de data MYSQL

Tags: mysql, html5, node.js, express.js

Estou fazendo um sistema de gerenciamento de hotel usando Javascript, NodeJS, Express e MYSQL.
Eu preciso que o meu formato de data seja do tipo DIA/MÊS/ANO, desta forma:

```
DATE_FORMAT(dt_entrada, '%d/%m/%Y')
DATE_FORMAT(dt_saida, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Meu código SQL está deste jeito

```
SELECT id_reserva, quarto.num_quarto, nome, DATE_FORMAT(dt_entrada, 
'%d/%m/%Y'), DATE_FORMAT(dt_saida, '%d/%m/%Y') from reserva, quarto, cliente 
WHERE reserva.id_cliente = cliente.id_cliente and reserva.num_quarto = 
quarto.num_quarto
```

Porém, quando faço um console.log(rows), ele me aparece isto.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O nome da propriedade do meu banco de dados acaba mudando para DATE_FORMAT...
Sendo que ele é dt_entrada e dt_saida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta adicionar um alias,
ex:
DATE_FORMAT(dt_entrada, 
'%d/%m/%Y') as dt_entrada